# EE to manage static content: How would you do this?

Tags: php, expressionengine

I'm in a weird place with this new project: I have a client with a working Javascript application and they want to manage the text elements with a CMS. The native JS environment would be leading.

Ideally, EE would manage content and then render to static files in a content directory. I'm not a PHP guy and my experience with EE content has always been dynamic, using it's tags. Now I need to pre-render the content to a file or url, outside the template directory...so I could use some guidance.

Something like this works:

```
{exp:channel:entries
    channel="content"
    disable="categories|category_fields|member_data|pagination|trackbacks"
    status="Open"
    dynamic="no"
    limit="1"
}

<?php 
 $File = "./articles/YourFile.html"; 
 $Handle = fopen($File, 'w');
 $Data = "<h1>{title}</h1>\n<hr /><p>{base_body}</p>\n"; 
 fwrite($Handle, $Data); 
 print "Data Written"; 
 fclose($Handle); 
 ?>

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

But I actually have to manually view the page to render content... is there a way around this? Can I use EE as an service? An example on how to render the above content would be helpful..I'm getting my head around services today too..

Comment: Sounds like MovableType :) 

The functionality you're looks for does not exists as far as I know. Do you actually need to read a file from the system? or would it be possible to curl a url (even a local one)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I've set up previously to get a static file of an EE template.

I setup my EE template like normal. Then set up a PHP script which uses CURL to call the template URL and write the contents to a static file. I set up a cron to run the file at the interval I need.

The PHP script file and the output PHP or TXT file (or whatever you need it to be named) are in the same directory. Make sure the output file has 777 permissions.

This is what you would put in the php script file. Just change the $site and $filename variables to what you want to use:

```
set_time_limit(3450);

#GRAB  DATA
$site = "http://www.domain.com/template-group/template";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$site);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
$result=curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

#WRITE  DATA TO FILE
$filename = 'static-file-name.php';
if (is_writable($filename)) {
    if (!$handle = fopen($filename, 'w')) {
         echo "Cannot open file ($filename)";
         exit;
    }
    if (fwrite($handle, $result) === FALSE) {
        echo "Cannot write to file ($filename)";
        exit;
    }
    echo "Success, updated the accordion file";
    fclose($handle);
} else  echo "The file $filename is not writable";
```

Your EE template would look like this:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="content" disable="categories|category_fields|member_data|pagination|trackbacks" status="Open" dynamic="no" limit="1" }
      <h1>{title}</h1>
      <hr />
      <p>{base_body}</p>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing about EE is that the content within the system doesn't translate into a page or url. Channel data is dynamic and often intermingled with data from other sources (global variables, multiple channels, low vars, the list goes on).

The best way (that I can think of) to do this would be to write a extension that would trigger a file to be written to the system when an entry is saved. You're already part of the way there with the php you have running in your template.

Checkout out the [entry_submission_end](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/development/extension_hooks/api/channel_entries/index.html#id5) hook for use in the extension if you go this route.  The trick is to figure out what you're outputting. Since channel data isn't necessarily related to a template you'll need to choose a template to render the channel data in or use the pages module to allow the user to select a template within EE.

This isn't 100% a solution to your question, but it should point you in the direction you need to go.